# Designing a calendar and scheduling event using ASP.net for all employees in office

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, angular, fullcalendar

I need advice on how to connect the following for a web application that I am trying to develop.

The web application is being developed using .ASP net. The application asks the user to create a

1.login

2.add,delete,update events to a calendar.

3. Should have an universal calendar for specific functionalities for example it should show all the meetings that are held on a specific date, or the employees who are on leave on that date.

So far I have gotten to do 1. and 2.

For point 2, I have developed the calendar which can handle the addition, deletion and update well. but I am not understanding how to connect it for all employees. When the user signs up for the calendar user service, I want to him to have the calendar. And then he can manipulate the calendar events.There is only one SQL table called events and it has the fields

-event_id

-title

-startTime

-Description

-EndTime.

So the the problem I want to solve is how to integrate when every time an employee signs up, he has his own personal calendar and his own schedule. Moreover, I want to know how  to include a unique calender so that the entire office can see the global events like meetings, or leaves of employees (in the job description this will be provided)

Thanks for your time in reading this, and it will be really helpful if you can assist me in working around this problem.
Cheers

Comment: as a user ID to the events table. Or if the same event can be associated with multiple users, use an intermediary table with event ID and user ID columns. It's basic entity-relationship design. Then use a WHERE clause / joins in your SQL to get the events just for that user into the calendar. Maybe if you need "global" events you could have another special flag field for this. But of all this sounds suspiciously like what Outlook/Exchange can do (and likely do it better), or Google Calendar, etc etc. Is any of this a feature not already available in a package the company probably already has?

Answer (score 0):

Create a field userCalendar_id in table of users login or user profile also have an other field userCalendar_id in your common calendar where you can save the user id as unique calendar id and it also gives you to flexibility of having the unique calendar for every employee & you also can from a major calendar which can show all the events of employees for particular day.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

So every time the user fills out the form, do I generate a random_id and assign that id to userCalender_id?

Could you kindly elaborate more on the major calendar part? What if I want more than a day or week?

Comment: Yes your correct, you need to create an extra field in calendar table to store other users events, you may the user id it self as primary key to make the difference. For day or a week you can set the start date & time to end date & time

Answer (score 0):

If log-in is Active Directory:
Create an employee_email field in your calendar (events) table.  When the user goes to the form page, pass the e-mail to a hidden field within the form.  When they submit the form, the e-mail is submitted along with the event data.

If the log-in is from database:
Create an ID field in the calendar (events) table that matches the ID field from your employees table.  When the user goes to the form page, pass the User's ID in a querystring or session variable and store it in a hidden field on the form.  When they submit the form, the value in the hidden ID field is submitted along with the event data.